# How to save in session?

Tags: php, mysql

How can i save a session in php so that when i click value in td tag it will save a session and redirect into another page?
this is my code:

```
<?
$sql = "SELECT * from members";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<tr><td><img src='. $row1['propict'] .' width="70" height="70" /></td><td name="frnd"><a href="fprofile.php">' . $row1['name'] . '</td>';
    } 
?>
```

what i want here is when i click name that shows from td i will be redirected to fprofile.php that contain the information base on the name i clicked.
please help me guys to do this i really need to know this information.

Comment: Use an `<a>` element.

Comment: `<td name="frnd"><a href="fprofile.php?user='.$row1['name'].'">'.$row1['name'].'</a></td>`?

Comment: yea i used it but what i want is to show the specific content from the td i clicked

Comment: Unless this is some legacy application, you have no reason to use `mysql_query` in this day and age.

Comment: This user is not familiar with PHP at all. This user is coding via StackOverflow answers. See their profile and previous question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$sql = "SELECT * from members";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    echo "<tr><td><img src='. $row1['propict'] .' width='70' height='70' /> </td>";

    echo "<td name='frnd'><a href='fprofile.php?name=". $rows['name']. "'>" . 
    $row1['name'] . '</td>';

} 
?>
```

and in fprofile.php

```
$_SESSION['name']= $_GET['name'];
```

now the clicked name is in the variable of `$_SESSION['name']`
just tell me if there is a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways of doing the same :-

1). You can follow this approach also, but the user name will be displayed in the url.
Like:-

### http://googl.com/aba.php?name=dinesh

```
<?
$sql = "SELECT * from members";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<tr>
    <td><img src='. $row1['propict'] .' width="70" height="70" /></td>
    <td name="frnd" onClick="showUserInfo('$row1[name]')"><a href="fprofile.php">' . $row1['name'] . '</td>';
    } 
?>
```

Js function write just below of you code..

```
function showUserInfo(name) {
  window.location= <YOUR BASE URL>+'user_info.php?name='+name;
}
```

2). The name can also be set in the SESSION by AJAX also. This is a bite long approach but the name will not be displayed in the url.

You need to follow the following steps.

```
<?
$sql = "SELECT * from members";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<tr>
    <td><img src='. $row1['propict'] .' width="70" height="70" /></td>
    <td name="frnd" onClick="showUserInfo('$row1[name]')"><a href="fprofile.php">' . $row1['name'] . '</td>';
    } 
?>
```

JS function:---

Write the name in session in set_name_in_session.php file, then redirect the control to user_info.php page. There read the user name in user_info.php page and fetch the user details..

```
function showUserInfo(user_name) {
  $.ajax({
    url: <BASE_URL_OF_YOUR_SITE>+'set_name_in_session.php', //SET THE SESSION IN THIS FILE
    data: {name: user_name},
    method:'post',
    success:function(response) {
      window.location = <BASE_URL_OF_YOUR_SITE>+"user_info.php";
    }

  });
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you can write the user id in the SESSION rather than user name. Because might be possible the two or more users have the same name

Answer (score -1):

Update the link so that it passes the name you want to store in the session.

```
 <a href="fprofile.php?name=' . $row1['name'] . '">' .$row1['name'] . '</td>
```

In fprofile.php, detect if $_GET['name'] has been set, and store it in the session.

```
if (isset($_GET['name']) && !empty($_GET['name'])) {
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_GET['name'];
}
```

This assumes you are auto starting your session.

You can use $_REQUEST instead of $_GET to handle POST and GET requests similarly.

Comment: Why the downvote? The answer addresses the question:  How to save a session. You are already directing to another page, via the <a> link. Or did you want another page after that?

Comment: it isn't me who voted you down, i think this code only stores name into a link. the above code is showing 3 rows from the database and each name has its information, fprofile.php has td that will show name, age, gender etc. i want to show all of it when i press its name to members.php to fprofile.php

Comment: Then perhaps you should say that in your question. If you don't ask the right question, you won't get the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Also, rather than passing all the info from the main program to fprofile.php, you could just pass the unique id for the members table, and refind the specific members record, and display that information. Since you haven't supplied what the members table looks like, a guess of the SQL is `select * from members where members.id = ?`